# Cannot connect to ODBC using user DSN after ImpersonateLoggedOnUser

Tags: c++, windows, odbc, impersonation, apache-phoenix

I am currently using Phoenix ODBC driver. I can only access phoenix with a certain user. When i use SQLDriverConnect with both users it works. But if i call ImpersonateLoggedOnUser then SQLDriverConnect cannot find the DSN. It give me following error.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Code is some what as follows. Could you help me please.

```
//login with user
DWORD     dwSize;
HANDLE    hToken;
LPVOID    lpvEnv;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
STARTUPINFO         si = {0};
WCHAR               szUserProfile[256] = L"";


TCHAR * tstrUserName = L"USERNAME" ;
TCHAR * tstrPassword = L"PASSWORD" ;

si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
if (!LogonUser( 
    tstrUserName, 
    NULL, 
    tstrPassword, 
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, 
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, 
    &hToken
    )
)
{
    auto value = GetLastError();
    throw "Cannot Login With ANOTHER USER";
}

ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
w_char *connectionString = L"DSN=Phoenix";
SQL_ENVIRONMENT env;
SQL_DBC_HANDLE dbcHandle;


if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env) == SQL_ERROR)
{
    throw;
}

// Register this as an application that expects 3.x behavior,
// you must register something if you use AllocHandle
SQLSetEnvAttr(env,
            SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
            (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3,
            0);

//allocate a connection
RETCODE ret = 0;
ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbcHandle);
if(ret == SQL_ERROR || dbcHandle == nullptr )
    throw;

//connect with driver to odbc
ret = SQLDriverConnect( dbcHandle, 
    nullptr, 
    connectionString,
    SQL_NTS,
    nullptr,
    0,
    nullptr,
    SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code all looks sensible. However, check the easy stuff first, when you created the the data source in odbc...

- did you create it in the users or system section (it will need to be a system dns entry to be seen by the user you are impersonating
- is your program a 32 bit or a 64 bit executable as you could have also created it on the incorrect odbc manager (there is one in c:\windows\system32 (the 64 bit version) and one in c:\windows\sysWow64 (the 32bit version)

Comment: Yes i have checked actually. It works when start process with runas with correct user id and commenting ImpersonateLoggedOnUser. I have also tested the code with normal user SQLDriverConnect works normal just i cannot read data, i get exception that i do not have rights to read or write data.

Regards,